# Google Cloud Function can't call firestore.get(), this._firestore.getAll is not a function at DocumentReference.get

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get a Firestore document in my google cloud function, but the Firebase Admin SDK is throwing an error, and I am not sure how to fix an error with the Admin SDK library. I have updated the `firebase-admin` dependency to ^8.0.0 to no avail.

```
TypeError: this._firestore.getAll is not a function at DocumentReference.get
 (***/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:198:32) at updateClaims (***/functions/index.js:49:22)
```

This is the relevant areas of my code, shortened for clarity:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firestore = admin.firestore.Firestore; /// Tried calling admin.firestore.DocumentReference(...); as well...
admin.initializeApp();


/// ...

/// Private function member that updates the user's claims, with UID cleaned by userWriteClaims
const updateClaims = async (userid) => {
 let userIndexRef = new firestore.DocumentReference('Users/' + userid);
 return userIndexRef.get().then(documentSnapshot => {
  /// @TODO: my logic here
 })
};

const errorMessage = (error, code) => {
 /// ...
};

/// Public-facing HTTPS endpoint 
exports.userWriteClaims = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
 /// function verifies user exists, then calls:
 response.send(await updateClaims(request.query.uid));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had forgotten to initialise a new Firestore Instance, which needed to be done separately from admin SDK.

This required two changes compared to above:

```
const firestore = new admin.firestore.Firestore;
```

```
let userIndexRef = firestore.doc('Users/' + userid);
```

Comment: `admin.firestore()` gives you access to the database instance. Then you can do `admin.firestore().collection('foo').doc('bar')` and so on.